# How to Pause or Stop Audio &/or Video onPageChange

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio

I'm still new at Javascript so PLEASE be kind. I have several separate pages in my html. The nav has 6 links (home, music, about, gigs, lyrics, contact. The nav home page has a youtube vid embedded. There is also a nav music page which incorporates 5 album/cds each with it's own playlist/audio player. How can I stop the video and/or audio from playing when the page changes?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#home').load('home.html');
  $('#music').load('player.html');
  $('#about').load('about.html');
  $('#gigs').load('gigs.html');
  $('#contact').load('contact.html');
});
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="hambtn" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</div>
  <div id="sidenav" class="menu">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
    <a href="#home">home</a>
    <a href="#music">music</a>
    <a href="#about">about</a>
    <a href="#gigs">gigs</a>
    <a href="#contact"><span>contact</span></a>
  </div>
</nav>
<section>
  <article>
    <div id="home"></div>
    <div id="music"></div>
  </article>
</section>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>6-24_jj utube responsive</title>
<style type="text/css">
#utube{
 margin:0 auto;
 width:80%;
 height:auto;
}
.video-responsive{
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-bottom:56.25%;
    position:relative;
    height:0;
}
.video-responsive iframe{
    left:0;
    top:0;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="utube" class="video-responsive"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ScMzIvxBSi4?rel=0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to show the YouTube iframe on all pages?  If not, why not just remove it from the DOM?  It isn't clear to me how the two pages you've shown interact.

Comment: One page is the home page which has the youtube video and another page is the music page which has the audio. If the video is playing on the home page and then the nav>music is clicked the video doesn't stop unless the stop is clicked on the youtube video itself. I'm trying to have the video &/or the audio stop if the user clicks on a different nav page (ie..home, music, about, etc)

Comment: Why not just load content into the same place then?  Why have a separate div for home, and music?

Comment: The home page content is going to change throughout time whereas the music (albums) page will never be changed. That's why there different pages.

Comment: So, you want to keep the music part showing at all times, but you want to stop it playing when the page changes?

Comment: Kind of....I'm re-building an old site that isn't mobile friendly (ie...it doesn't re-size for screen sizes). The old site had iframes that would change in a main div. Now it is a scrollable site with sections for each page. If any one of the audio is playing and the user decides to check out say the about section, the music &/or video keeps playing. I would like to stop this if the focus changes to another page. It's seems I'm having a hard time explaining...sorry

Comment: I think the Dom idea might work. I can add or remove it through the Dom?

Answer (score 0):

You can pause audio or video with 
.pause()
and play audio or video with 
.play()